# Cloning Hidden Elements in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I'm building a simple application that allows the user to add X number of 'somethings'.

So for each 'something', there is a small form with a few fields. They can add as many somethings as they like by clicking a button like 'Add new something'.

Each time they add a new something, they will get a new instance of this form to fill out.

What is the best way to duplicate the form each time? I was going to just have a hidden (with `display: none;`) version of the form that I clone each time, but I've also noticed people putting their hidden clones in a `script` tag. I looked around for an article on pros/cons of this method but couldn't find anything.

Comment: If you have a reset form function then clone the form, then trigger the reset function on it.

Answer (score 2):

I Think, You need something like this,

#### HTML Markup

```
<div id="comment-template" style="display:none;">
    <li class="comment">
        <div class="comment-author">
            <input type="text" name="author" id="author" />
        </div>
        <div class="comment-body">
            <input type="text" name="author" id="author" />
        </div>
        <div class="comment-actions"> <a href="#reply" class="reply">Reply</a>

        </div>
    </li>
</div>
<ul id="comments"></ul>
<button id="add" onclick="Addit()">Add</button>
```

#### JS Code

```
function Addit() {
    var commentsList = document.getElementById('comments');
    var tmpl = document.getElementById('comment-template').innerHTML;
    commentsList.innerHTML=commentsList.innerHTML+tmpl;
}
```

### Example Fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can try HTML5 [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

There's a great article about it in [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/), here is an example:

```
<button onclick="useIt()">Use me</button>
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
  function useIt() {
    var content = document.querySelector('template').content;
    // Update something in the template DOM.
    var span = content.querySelector('span');
    span.textContent = parseInt(span.textContent) + 1;
    document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(
        document.importNode(content, true));
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div>Template used: <span>0</span></div>
  <script>alert('Thanks!')</script>
</template>
```

Comment: This looks cool, browser support is lacking a bit right now though unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't make a big difference - do whatever seems more practical to you. If it's on a public website that is accessible to everyone, maybe it would be better to put the 'duplicate-form' in the JS code since spam-robots might go through your HTML code and submit the hidden form.